# Call Observer's onNext metod in Observable.defer

Tags: android, rx-android, reactivex

I'm a new reactive programmer. I wanted to call the  observer's `onNext` method in defer is there any good way for doing it?

Take for example-

```
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super String> observer) {
        try {
            if (!observer.isUnsubscribed()) {

                // While using create, can call observer.onNext        
                for(int i=0;i< 10 ;i++)
                    observer.onNext("");

                observer.onCompleted();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            observer.onError(e);
        }
    }
});

Observable.defer( new Func0<Observable<String>>() {

    @Override
    public Observable<String> call() {

        // I want call observer.onNext("") here   

                 return Observable.just("");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you can only call onNext from one subscriber. I would say to create one subscriber and then call onNext from this subscriber, something like this:

```
final Subscriber<String> subscriber = new Subscriber<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(String s) {

        }
    };

    Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<String>>() {

        @Override
        public Observable<String> call() {

            // I want call observer.onNext("") here

            subscriber.onNext("Test");
            return Observable.just("dasdsa");
        }

    });
```

But, you can also subscribe this observable which would call this "onNext" inside the subscribe method, like this:

```
Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<String>>() {

        @Override
        public Observable<String> call() {

            // I want call observer.onNext("") here
            return Observable.just("dasdsa");
        }

    }).subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
        @Override
        public void call(String s) {
            //on Next was called after the subscribe
        }
    });
```

I think its up to you to decide what is more useful, I hope I was able to help!